# How to let user decide if he wants shortcut on the desktop in NSIS (Nullsoft Scriptable Install System)?

Tags: installation, nsis

As in the question I want to let user decide if he/she wants desktop shortcut of my application or not using NSIS. I was trying to do it using custom pages, but no luck.

Maybe someone did it before and will be willing to share the script?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This has been answered (with a better answer) in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517471/how-to-add-a-desktop-shortcut-option-on-finish-page-in-nsis-installer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way is to just use a section and the component page takes care of it

If you go for the custom page option (overkill IMHO), you could store the result in a global variable or just toggle the (hidden) section directly with the helper macros in section.nsh

Note: I'm pretty sure the MS guidelines tells you not to create a desktop shortcut

Comment: You are right.. after reading a little more I got it using sections ;) But I just started using NSIS today so I hope I'm excused :)