# Customizing an exsisting NSIS MUI2 page

Tags: checkbox, nsis, nsis-mui

I have added a checkbox successfully to nsis installer's finish page defining functions for `MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_PRE` and `MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW` in finish page using `MUI`.

But if I include `MUI2` instead of `MUI`, the check box is not displayed. I suppose there is something different in `MUI2` than `MUI` with respect to this. I could not find documentation on that an if anyone knows that, can I please know???

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MUI1 uses InstallOptions for the Welcome and Finish pages and MUI2 uses nsDialogs.

This is documented in the [MUI2 readme](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Modern%20UI%202/Readme.html):

> The welcome and finish page are no
>   longer implemented using
>   InstallOptions. Instead, the new
>   nsDialogs plug-in is used. nsDialogs
>   allows you to create custom pages or
>   customize existing pages directly from
>   the script.

**Edit:** Customize the page by using the nsDialogs commands in the show callback:

```
var Checkbox

Function MyFinishShow
${NSD_CreateCheckbox} 120u 110u 100% 10u "&Something"
Pop $Checkbox
SetCtlColors $Checkbox "" "ffffff"
FunctionEnd

Function MyFinishLeave
${NSD_GetState} $Checkbox $0
${If} $0 <> 0
    MessageBox mb_ok "Custom checkbox was checked..."
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd

!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_RUN "calc.exe" ;See note after the code...
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW MyFinishShow
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_LEAVE MyFinishLeave
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH
```

Or if you are not using the existing finish page checkboxes, you can use those for [custom stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517471/how-to-add-a-desktop-shortcut-option-on-finish-page-in-nsis-installer/1517851#1517851) without using the show callback...

Comment: Thanks for your anwer. I ve found those words in MUI2. Also I referred to Winamp forums. http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?t=314012 exactly describes my question and it refers to http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?threadid=310323 where it says to add a custom page for finish page. But the above readme says we can customize an exsisting page... I just want to know how to achieve that? Thanks

Comment: @dia: Again, from the docs "Then, the show function is called, which can be used to customize the interface"

Comment: I can't manage this to work. [Documentation says](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Docs/nsDialogs/Readme.html): "`NSD_Create*` - A dialog must exist for this to work, so `nsDialogs::Create` must be called prior to this function.".

Comment: @Paul Make sure you are using MUI2.nsh if you want to use the code from this answer

Comment: The problem is that I'm trying to apply that to an uninstall dialog, and [you said it's not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43258310/2604492). Too bad that it's so complicated to add a checkbox.

Comment: @Paul That answer you linked to has all the information. MUI_UI is the easy route.