# How to get user input during windows installer for WinForms application?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, installation

I have a call tracking application that I've built and now I need to create a Windows Installer that bundles the .NET Framework 4.0 with the installer and also allows the user to enter a authentication id, when installing the application.

Then be able to get the value they entered to setup the application for their specific location, by setting an application setting, within the WinForms application.

If the installer can write the authentication id to the registry, I could grab it from there in my application, on startup.

Just not sure which installer to use that would make this as painless as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of the things in your question can be done by using Visual Studio Setup projects. But bit painful procedure. Do google search for finding resources about writing to registry and grabbing values at the start-up.

There may be other tools that give these functionalities in a more user-friendly way. I know only about Visual Studio Installer.

[This](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/vsSetupCustomDialogs.aspx) article explains about adding custom dialog boxes.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is completely easily can be done using [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) (Nullsoft Scriptable Install System). It enables script based creation of installers and it lets writing of installers, customize and add features and do whatever you want using its own set of commands. You may add any control to any page (text boxes, check boxes etc.) and add any number of custom pages and do whatever you want. It has its own compiler and the script you write can be compiled using it and be compressed usefully.

See the below post too:
[Customizing an exsisting NSIS MUI2 page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531115/customizing-an-exsisting-nsis-mui2-page)

The NSIS and MUI (Modern User Interface) documentation, NSIS examples on NSIS site and winamp forums will help you at everything in your way...

Answer (score 1):

In Advanced Installer you can do that pretty easily, but it's costly though. [Check this tutorial](http://standaloneinstaller.com/how-to-get-and-save-user-input-during-installation-using-advanced-installer.html)