# Customizing the finish page of NSIS installer

Tags: checkbox, installation, nsis

I want to add a checkbox to the finish page of installer. I have already two checkboxes on finishpage, one for showing readme file and other for opening another link. Now I want to add third checkbox for opening home page of my application.

I am following the steps given in this question as this is the exact thing which I want to achieve 
[Customizing an exsisting NSIS MUI2 page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531115/customizing-an-exsisting-nsis-mui2-page)

but the third checkbox is not appearing on finishpage. I am using MUI2.

Here is my code

```
!include "MUI2.nsh" 

var newCheckBox
Function showNewCheckbox
${NSD_CreateCheckbox} 50u 60u 100% 10u "&Launch Google"
Pop $newCheckBox
FunctionEnd

Function launchNewLink
${NSD_GetState} $newCheckBox $0
${If} $0 <> 0
    ExecShell "open" "http://google.com"
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd

Function LaunchLink
  ExecShell "open" "http://yahoo.com"
FunctionEnd


!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_NOAUTOCLOSE
!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_RUN
!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_RUN_NOTCHECKED
!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_RUN_TEXT "Open yahoo"
!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_RUN_FUNCTION "LaunchLink"
!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_SHOWREADME_NOTCHECKED
!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_SHOWREADME "${README_FILE}"
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW showNewCheckbox
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_LEAVE launchNewLink
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH
```

Am I missing something??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$newCheckBox` is a number != 0 it means the control was created, maybe its just behind the image on the left? Try 120u 175u as the first two numbers.

If you don't need a checkbox you can just use the link:

```
!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_LINK "My website"
!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_LINK_LOCATION "http://example.com"
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH
```

Comment: Thanks Anders! It was indeed hiding behind the image...It didnt occur to me

Comment: Can i change the link color?

Comment: @JorgeB.: SetCtlColors

Comment: @JorgeB: And what do you expect me to do about it? All of SourceForge have/had problems. Just read the helpfile that is installed with NSIS...

Comment: @Anders thank you. I don't expect anything. "API is offline" was my justification to don't know how to change color.

Comment: `MUI_FINISHPAGE_LINK_COLOR "RRGGBB"`