# Add checkbox in finish page of nsis installer window

Tags: nsis

How can I add a checkbox on finish page of nsis installer window?

I want to add a checkbox on finish page of nsis installer window. If the user check that checkbox then another `.exe` should start.

Answer (score 3):

NSIS already supports this: [MUI_FINISHPAGE_RUN](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Modern%20UI/Readme.html).

You can even force MUI_FINISHPAGE_SHOWREADME to also [look and do whatever you want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517471/how-to-add-a-desktop-shortcut-option-on-finish-page-in-nsis-installer/1517851#1517851)...

Comment: could u tell the step by step for adding the checkbox on finish page of nsis installer window ?

Comment: @PauloCarvalho: What are you talking about? I linked to the MUI documentation. Click the first link in my answer, click "Expand all" and search for "_RUN".

Answer (score -1):

```
!include nsDialogs.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh

Name nsDialogs
OutFile nsDialogs.exe

XPStyle on
Var Dialog
Var Checkbox

Page custom nsDialogsPage
Page license
Page instfiles

Function nsDialogsPage
    nsDialogs::Create 1018
    Pop $Dialog
    ${If} $Dialog == error
        Abort
    ${EndIf}    
    ${NSD_CreateCheckbox} 0 30u 100% 10u "&Something"
    Pop $Checkbox
    ${If} $Checkbox_State == ${BST_CHECKED}
        ${NSD_Check} $Checkbox
    ${EndIf}
    # alternative for the above ${If}:
    #${NSD_SetState} $Checkbox_State
    nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd


Section
    DetailPrint "hello world"
SectionEnd
```

Comment: Can you please take some time to properly format your code?