# Adding a checkbox to the NSIS Uninstaller Welcome Page

Tags: nsis, uninstallation, nsdialogs, nsis-mui

I'm trying to add a checkbox to the welcome screen of my NSIS uninstaller, but I'm having trouble finding an example. From the [documentation](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Modern%20UI/Readme.html) for MUI2 I can't find any custom functions that can be run on the welcome page.

It looks like the finish page is more easy to customize based on the documentation and other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517471/how-to-add-a-desktop-shortcut-option-on-finish-page-in-nsis-installer)s I've found.

Is there a way to customize the Welcome Page? If not, what are the other options for accomplishing the intent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MUI(1) documentation you linked to has a note about how you can customize the welcome page in the pre/show callbacks. With MUI2 you can add controls in the show callback. See the nsDialogs documentation for more information about these custom controls...

```
!include MUI2.nsh
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW un.ModifyUnWelcome
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_LEAVE un.LeaveUnWelcome
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_WELCOME
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE English

Var mycheckbox ; You could just store the HWND in $1 etc if you don't want this extra variable

Function un.ModifyUnWelcome
${NSD_CreateCheckbox} 120u -18u 50% 12u "Do something special"
Pop $mycheckbox
SetCtlColors $mycheckbox "" ${MUI_BGCOLOR}
${NSD_Check} $mycheckbox ; Check it by default
FunctionEnd

Function un.LeaveUnWelcome
${NSD_GetState} $mycheckbox $0
${If} $0 <> 0
    MessageBox mb_ok "I'm special"
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd

Section testuninstaller
Initpluginsdir
WriteUninstaller "$pluginsdir\u.exe"
ExecWait '"$pluginsdir\u.exe" _?=$pluginsdir'
Sectionend
```

Comment: The checkbox had the problems for me that it wouldn't it be clickeable on all of its surface. I've altered the coordinates to make it work: `120u -20u 50% 20u`